# Choropleth Map in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to reproduce the Choropleth Map given [here](http://blog.revolutionanalytics.com/2009/11/choropleth-challenge-result.html) with the code provided [by Hadley](https://gist.github.com/hadley/233134).

```
library(ggplot2)
library(maps)
 
# First (and most annoying) task - get matching state and county variables 
# for both datasets.  And unfortauntely it's not quite right, as you can
# see from the finish product - some counties are missing.
unemp <- read.csv("unemployment09.csv", header = F, stringsAsFactors = F)
names(unemp) <- c("id", "state_fips", "county_fips", "name", "year", 
  "?", "?", "?", "rate")
unemp$county <- tolower(gsub(" County, [A-Z]{2}", "", unemp$name))
unemp$state <- gsub("^.*([A-Z]{2}).*$", "\\1", unemp$name)
 
county_df <- map_data("county")
names(county_df) <- c("long", "lat", "group", "order", "state_name", "county")
county_df$state <- state.abb[match(county_df$state_name, tolower(state.name))]
county_df$state_name <- NULL
 
state_df <- map_data("state")
 
# Combine together 
choropleth <- merge(county_df, unemp, by = c("state", "county"))
choropleth <- choropleth[order(choropleth$order), ]
# Discretise rate to use with Brewer colour scheme - many options here
# choropleth$rate_d <- cut_number(choropleth$rate, 5)
# choropleth$rate_d <- cut_interval(choropleth$rate, 5)
# Nathan's choice is a little odd:
choropleth$rate_d <- cut(choropleth$rate, breaks = c(seq(0, 10, by = 2), 35))
 
# Once you have the data in the right format, recreating the plot is straight
# forward.
 
ggplot(choropleth, aes(long, lat, group = group)) +
  geom_polygon(aes(fill = rate_d), colour = alpha("white", 1/2), size = 0.2) + 
  geom_polygon(data = state_df, colour = "white", fill = NA) +
  scale_fill_brewer(pal = "PuRd")
```

But this code gives the following error:

> ```
> Error in do.call("layer", list(mapping = mapping, data = data, stat = stat,  : 
>   could not find function "alpha"
> ```

Deleting alpha and using this code

```
ggplot(choropleth, aes(long, lat, group = group)) +
  geom_polygon(aes(fill = rate_d), colour = "white", size = 0.2) + 
  geom_polygon(data = state_df, colour = "white", fill = NA) +
  scale_fill_brewer(pal = "PuRd")
```

gives the following error:

> Error in scale_map.discrete(scale, df[[j]]) :    attempt to apply
> non-function

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Try loading the `scales` package.  I'm guessing this code you have is from before when scales was explicitly loaded by ggplot2 by default.

Comment: @TylerRinker: Thanks for your comment. Still have error even after loading scales package!!!

Comment: As Tyler mentioned, load the scales package to find the alpha() function, but the second error arises from `scale_fill_brewer()`; changing pal to palette worked for me.

Comment: Thanks @Dennis for your helpful comment. Could you change your comment to answer so I can accept it right answer for future OPs. Thanks

Comment: It's incomprehensible why `pal` and `palette` should make a difference, but it does...